# Embedding Current Date in Hive Insert

Tags: hive, hiveql, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to get the current date into a Hive database (version 0.13 running on an HDInsight cluster) with the following script

```
SET curdt = from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()); 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS curtime_test; 

CREATE TABLE curtime_test (
    dateEntered STRING
);

INSERT INTO TABLE curtime_test 
SELECT  '${hivevar:curdt}' FROM hivesampletable limit 3;

SELECT * FROM curtime_test;
```

Note that I want to have the same insert date for all the inserted records, this is a toy example, but the real one I want to use it on has millions of records to insert. This version I tried above just inserts the string '${hivevar:curdt}' into the database, which is not what I want:

```
${hivevar:curdt}
${hivevar:curdt}
${hivevar:curdt}
```

Omitting the quotes causes the insert to error out because of the spaces in the string. How can I do this right?

**Update:**
Using the line

```
SELECT  ${hiveconf:curdt} FROM hivesampletable limit 3;
```

as per the comment from Charlie Haley (I mixed up ${hivevar} and ${hiveconf}), gives me the results that I want. If he writes it up as an answer I will mark it as right.

Comment: Do you mean ${hiveconf:curdt} ? I have not seen hivevar used there before.

Comment: Did you try a "temporary macro" instead? OK, this would give different timestamps on each call, and there's a notorious bug if you have more than 1 macro call per query (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11432) but IMHO it's cleaner, syntax-wise.

Comment: Traveling, will look this evening

Comment: Charlie Haley was correct, I was confusing `hiveconf` with `hivevar`

Comment: Charlie Haley, any chance you can post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code sample works for me. Does this solve your problem?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS curtime_test; 

CREATE TABLE curtime_test (
    dateEntered STRING
);

INSERT INTO TABLE curtime_test 
SELECT  unix_timestamp() FROM hivesampletable limit 1;

SELECT * FROM curtime_test;
```

Comment: Note that my example is a toy one, I actually intend to insert millions of records, and then update them daily and this is the timestamp. However this code would give me a different timestamp per insert, right? That is why I needed a variable.